# how hdfs removes over-replicated blocks

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, replication

For example I wrote a file into HDFS using replication factor 2. The node I was writing to has now all the blocks of the file. Others copies of all blocks of the file are scattered around all remaining nodes in the cluster. That's default HDFS policy.
What exactly happens if I lower replication factor of the file to 1?
How HDFS decides which blocks from which nodes to delete? I hope it tries to delete blocks from nodes that have the most count of blocks of the file?

Why I'm asking - if it does, it would make sense - it will alleviate processing of the file. Because if there is only one copy of all blocks and all the blocks are located on the same node, then it would be harder to process the file using map-reduce because of data transferring to other nodes in the cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a block becomes `over-replicated`, the `name node` chooses a replica to remove. The `name node` will prefer not to reduce the number of racks that host replicas, and secondly prefer to remove a replica from the `data node` with the least amount of available disk space. This may help rebalancing the load over the cluster.

Source: [The Architecture of Open Source Applications](http://www.aosabook.org/en/hdfs.html)

Comment: It would be great if you also provide the of source of information (e.g. docs, or maybe you're contributing to HDFS and know the codebase).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a great writing.

Answer (score 1):

Over-replicated blocks are randomly removed from different nodes by the HDFS, and are rebalanced that means they are not just removed from the current node.

Comment: I know HDFS has 'rebalance' command in the meaning of rebalancing node usage from nodes' perspective, but I know nothing about file rebalancing Yes, HDFS tries to put file blocks on different nodes while writing or increasing replication factor, but it's not my question about. Could you link any documentation?

Comment: http://www.swiss-scalability.com/2013/08/hadoop-hdfs-balancer-explained.html; https://hadooptutorial.info/hdfs-rebalance/ ; http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_balancer.html ;  Please refer to this. I hope these will help.

Comment: This is what I said - rebalancing is only about rebalancing overall blocks concerning total space used on datanodes, racks involved. It's not about  separate files concerning how many blocks of the file is located on each datanode, as I asked in my question.

Comment: basically balancing and a replication factor are different topics